# Combine array and insert differences

Tags: javascript

Say i have two objects, `object_one`

```
{
  1: {item1 /*updated*/}, //note updated represents more recent item1 data
  2: {item1 /*updated*/},
  3: {item1 /*updated*/}
}
```

and `object_two`

```
{
  1: {item1, item2, item3},
  2: {item1, item2, item3},
  4: {item1, item2, item3},
  5: {item1, item2, item3}
}
```

I want to add the `object_one` into the `object_two`, adding any elements that the `object_two` doesn't have. I also want to take the `object_two`'s versions of item1 and update them to the value of `object_one`'s

**Desired result**

```
{
  1: {item1 /*updated*/, item2, item3},
  2: {item1 /*updated*/, item2, item3},
  3: {item1 /*updated*/},
  4: {item1, item2, item3},
  5: {item1, item2, item3}
}
```

I've tried doing it myself, but my solution was manual and didn't work for all lengths of `object_one` and `object_two`. Some direction would be much appreciated

Comment: What does `item1(updated)` resolve to? Is that a function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance its just pseudo code, ment to represent that the smaller object's values are more recent

Comment: the question is how can we think `item1(updated)===item1` so `item1(updated)` don't need to update?because they both have string `item1`?

Comment: updated question @xianshenglu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more info.

```js
// Original.
const original = {
  1: {A: '1A', B: '1B', C: '1C'},
  2: {A: '2A', B: '2B', C: '2C'},
  4: {A: '4A', B: '4B', C: '4C'},
  5: {A: '5A', B: '5B', C: '5C'}
}

// Merge.
const update = {
  1: {A: '1A updated'},
  2: {B: '2B updated'},
  3: {C: '3C updated'}
}

// Combine.
const merge = (original, update) => {
  const x = {...original}
  Object.entries(update).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    x[key] = Object.assign({}, x[key], value)
  })
  return x
}

// Output.
const output = merge(original, update)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```